# Streaming multiple IP cameras using OpenCV Python results in a lag

Tags: python, multithreading, ip-camera, opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano

We would like to periodically retrieve frames from an rtmp stream. For this, we have 2 IP cameras and use two separate threads to continuously refresh the frames. The main program creates the two streams and then calls: getFrame() on each thread, to retrieve the last frame from each camera. The system runs for 3 seconds and collected 3 frames from each stream (1 second in between). In the end, the program writes the images to disk.

We notice that there is a lag in the retrieval of the frames. When we request the frame at time x, the frame retrieved is the frame of a few seconds earlier. The lag is different for each camera and increases with the number of cameras added to the below code.

We looked into a few things already:
- We had the idea that the buffer of OpenCV was filled during the initialization. Therefore, we tried to remove the images from the buffer by calling the grab() method for 50 times before starting the main program.
- We used a Python queue to store the frames and then only grab the last frame added to the queue.

The camera datetime is synchronized with NTP and is displayed within the image. Comparing this datetime with the datetime of requesting the frame, results in an inconsistent lag. This varies for two cameras between 2 and 10 seconds. (somewhat similar to the OpenCV init time of two cameras)

The code is running on an Nvidia JetsonNano.

We use the following to store the images locally and give the: write time, camera number and epoch/iteration as file name:

```
def write_local(frames, epoch, names):
    for camera_number, image in enumerate(frames):
        name = names[camera_number]
        path = Path(".")
        if type(image) == np.ndarray:
            with io.BytesIO() as in_mem_file:
                path = path / "test_{0}_{1}_{2}.jpg".format(epoch, name, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace(" ", "_").replace('/', '-'))
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                image.save(in_mem_file, format='jpeg')
                image.seek(0)
                path.write_bytes(in_mem_file.getbuffer())
```

We use the following object for streaming multiple rtmp links:

```
class CameraStream:

    def __init__(self, rtmp_link=None):
        self.currentFrame = None
        self.CAMERA_WIDTH = 2560
        self.CAMERA_HEIGHT = 1920

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(rtmp_link)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.CAMERA_WIDTH)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.CAMERA_HEIGHT)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        Thread(target=self.updateFrame, args=()).start()

    def updateFrame(self):       
        while(True):
            ret, self.current_frame = self.capture.read()

    def getFrame(self):
        return self.current_frame
```

Initialize the camera's:

```
wig_0 = webcamImageGetter(rtmp_link= 'rtmp://..')
wig_0.start()

wig_1 = webcamImageGetter(rtmp_link= 'rtmp://..')
wig_1.start()
```

Start the session and collect each second a frame from the camera.

```
s = time.time()
time_sinds_last = 0
current_frames = []
while time.time() - s < 100:
    if time.time() - s > 1:
        # print the datetime when the frame is requested
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").replace(" ", "_").replace('/', '-'))
        # Collect frames and store in current_frames
        current_frames += [([wig_0.getFrame(), wig_1.getFrame()], len(current_frames), ['1_1', '1_2'])]
        s = time.time()

     # Stop after 3 epochs/iterations
     if len(current_frames) > 3:
        break
# write current frames to disk
for x in current_frames:
    write_local(frames=x[0], epoch=x[1], names=x[2])
```